# why I'm getting "Not Found: /api/v1.0/productos/${this.id_product}/"

Tags: django, vue.js

I got a problem with vue.js. I made a CRUD, and got an issue trying to use PUT to update.

when I applied this method to send update information to Django, an error appeared:

```
METHOD IN VUE.JS

methods: {
        onSubmit(evt){
            evt.preventDefault()
            
            const path = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1.0/productos/${this.id_product}/'

            axios.put(path, this.form).then((response) => {

                this.form.nombreProd = response.data.nombreProd
                this.form.precioProd = response.data.precioProd
                this.form.contenido = response.data.contenido
                this.form.descripcionProd = response.data.descripcionProd

                alert("Actualización exitosa")

            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })

        }
```

ANSWER IN DJANGO

Not Found: /api/v1.0/productos/${this.id_product}/
[02/Oct/2022 12:57:46] "PUT /api/v1.0/productos/$%7Bthis.id_product%7D/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2609

Trying to understand, I realized that it could be an issue with the curly braces, but I don´t know how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

There is issue where you are setting path. You have to use ` instead of ' when you add data property in string. So, path will be like:

```
const path = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1.0/productos/${this.id_product}/`
```